# What's the word for Self Reflection?

Tags: latin, greek

There's a Greek (maybe Latin) word for when you reflect on your work. Does anybody know what I'm talking about?

For instance, this would be used to describe a essay that you write to look back and reflect on your work during the past semester.

Comment: "Navel gazing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking of [metacognition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metacognition):

> Awareness or analysis of one's own learning or thinking processes (Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[introspection](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/introspection)*

> The examination or observation of one’s own mental and emotional processes:
>   *quiet introspection can be extremely valuable*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: Thank you. I believe the word is either Greek though.

Comment: @dfg If it were French, I might direct you to *recherche* a la [Proust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Search_of_Lost_Time)

Answer (score 0):

```
To look back and reflect on your work.
```

> **In retrospect** — that is, in looking back and contemplating the past — we sometimes find ourselves wishing that we had done some
>   things differently.
>
> Though this word most commonly appears as a noun in the phrase "in
>   retrospect," it can also be used as a verb.

*The prefix retro- means “back," and spect is a component of the words inspect, spectator, spectacles, and perspective, among others, which all have to do with looking or seeing*. **(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/retrospect)**)**

- Our cars and factories had clearly triggered a worldwide reaction, which [in retrospect](http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/retrospect) shouldn't surprise us.
- Again, this is not law but [in retrospect](http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/retrospect) it might have been sensible.